# Unit test cases for iOS compatibilty

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-location, core-bluetooth

A recent update to iOS made a seemly minor change in keychain and broke a lot of the functionality for our app. This change would have affected only apps that shares keychain with another app and runs mostly in the background. This change was not captured in any of iOS release notes/documents.

In order to stay on top of such a lapse again, we are planning on coming up with a suite of test apps/unit test cases that would test the main functionality on new versions of iOS.

Would this be considered unit testing or integration testing?

Taking Core Bluetooth as an example framework, my question is:

- What are the standard ways to test iOS BLE APIs?
- Would one use mock objects for interaction with peripheral, if the app is a central because we intend to test iOS BLE server/APIs not the BLE protocol itself?